# Regex to trim some unwanted characters in strings

Tags: regex, linux, string, unix

Given the following expressions:

```
SS-56789/2013/20

ST:MM-2ZTES/TEST

MM-2FKAP/TEST

ZZ/128TEST

TK:ZZ-TEST
```

and so on...

I would like to trim the 'MM', 'SS', 'ZZ', and 'MM-', 'SS-', 'ZZ-' character strings.

I tried this earlier: `SS-+` so I can trim strings containing all of the 'SS-' strings.

Is there a chance to trim all of the above char strgs only in ONE expression?

Or do I must to write 6 expression rows for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
(?:SS|MM|ZZ)-?
```

Replace the matched items with empty string to remove the unwanted characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the this pattern:

```
((M{2}|S{2}|Z{2})-?)
```

and a call to Replace with empty string will trim them.

If the string to trim always lies at the start of the line prefix the pattern with `^` like this:

```
^((M{2}|S{2}|Z{2})-?)
```